# Facebook Messages access via imap

Tags: facebook, imap, pop3, email-client, facebook-messages

Does anybody know if is possible to access facebook messages via imap or pop to manage facebook messages within an email client?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not possible. Only the [publicly documented APIs](https://developers.facebook.com) are available.

See especially the `inbox` connection of the [User object](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/)

Answer (score 1):

This [Article](http://www.emailserviceguide.com/2010/01/making-facebooks-messaging-system-imap-compatible/) propose a way to read and store facebook message:

The process is done through the following steps:

- **Logging in** : Logging in might be one of the trickier parts. The way you login to an IMAP server is to use the following command:

  LOGIN username password
- **Listing folders** : The command you’d issue to the IMAP server is:

  `LIST "" *`

> Since we know from the Mailbox folder API description, there are only
>   three folders. These folders are:
>
> ```
> Inbox (folder_id 0)
> Outbox (folder_id 1)
> Updates (folder_id 4)
> ```
>
> With this in mind, we can hard code the following response to the list
>   command:
>
> ```
> LIST (\HasChildren) "/" Inbox
> LIST (\HasChildren) "/" Outbox
> LIST (\HasChildren) "/" Updates
> ```
>
> - **Selecting a folder** : In IMAP, you use the following command to select a folder:
>
>   `SELECT folder-name`
> - **Getting message content:** The key in getting messages trough IMAP is a command named FETCH. The FETCH command comes with a lot of
>     different modes, but we’ll focus on the most fundamental ones. These
>     are (AFAIK) FLAGS, RFC822, RFC822.HEADER, RFC822.TEXT, RFC822.SIZE and
>     UID. Since RFC822 is just RFC822.HEADER and RFC822.TEXT combined, we
>     have one less variable to worry about.
> - **FETCH UID** Let’s start with UID, as this is the easiest one. You’d issue this command as follows:
>
>   `FETCH 1:6 (UID)`
>
> The expected result would look something like this:
>
> ```
> 1 FETCH (UID 1029955483)
> 2 FETCH (UID 1029955484)
> 3 FETCH (UID 1029955485)
> 4 FETCH (UID 1029955486)
> 5 FETCH (UID 1029955487)
> 6 FETCH (UID 1029955488)
> ```
>
> The equivalent command in Facebook’s API would be something like this
>   (I’m not sure if it’s possible to combine queries like this, but you
>   get the idea):
>
> ```
> SELECT message_id FROM message WHERE thread_id IN (SELECT thread_id FROM thread WHERE folder_id = 0)
> ```
>
> You would then use that output as the UID.

More operations are available in http://www.emailserviceguide.com/2010/01/making-facebooks-messaging-system-imap-compatible/